# Changing Pattern Size in Html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas

**My Problem:** I've got an ImageObject, that is being used to create a PatternObject. My problem is, that i changed the `width` and `height` properties of the Image before creating the pattern, but that doesn't actually remap the image (and that is also no problem). The thing is, that I now have got a pattern, that is of a different size (the original image size) than the image itself. If I want to draw a line with the fillStyle of that pattern, it doesn't fit (because I need a pattern of the new size).

**My question:** Is there an easy way, to achieve that the pattern's width and height can be adjusted?

***My tries*** and why I dont like them:

1) Render the original image to a canvas with the new size and create the pattern from that. Didn't use this, because the pattern cannot be loaded directly as a result of the canvas being created and rendered to too slowly. But I want that pattern directly

2) Calculate the variance between the new image size and the original one, change the lineWidth of the context, so the patterns height fits exactly and scale the line down, so it has a nice size. Didn't use that because I render in realtime and this is way too slow to be used later in webapps.

Answer (score 9):

Using canvas (your step 1) is the most flexible way.

It's not slower using a canvas to draw on another canvas than using an image directly. They both use the same element basis (you're blitting a bitmap just as you do with an image).

(**Update**: Drawing using pattern as style do go through an extra step of a local transformation matrix for the pattern in more recent browsers.)

Create a new canvas in the size of the pattern and simple draw the image into it:

```
patternCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, patternWidth, patternHeight);
```

Then use the canvas of patternCtx as basis for the pattern (internally the pattern caches this image the first time it's drawn, from there, if possible, it just doubles out what it has until the whole canvas is filled).

The other option is to pre-scale the images to all the sizes you need them to be, load them all in, and then choose the image which size is the one you need.

The third is to draw the image yourself as a pattern. This however is not so efficient compared to the built-in method, though using the above mentioned method (internal) you can get a usable result.

## Example of manual patterning:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  fillPattern(this, 64, 64);
  change.onchange = change.oninput = function() {
    fillPattern(img, this.value, this.value);
  }
};
img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/tkBVh.png";

// Fills canvas with image as pattern at size w,h
function fillPattern(img, w, h) {

    //draw once
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    while (w < canvas.width) {
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, w, 0);
        w <<= 1;  // shift left 1 = *2 but slightly faster
    }
    while (h < canvas.height) {
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, h);
        h <<= 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id=change type=range min=8 max=120 value=64><br>
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=400></canvas>
```

(or with a [video as pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/Lw656x6d/)).

Comment: +1 nice that you give me so many options, will try the first one again, my problem was that if i draw on the newly defined canvas and then try to load a pattern from it, the pattern can somehow not be loaded, because the canvas isn't ready loading.

Comment: @TheOneAndOnly No problem. The cause of that is more likely that the image wasn't finished loading. You can hook into image's onload event to then trigger the pattern setting etc.

Comment: This snippet is very useful! +1